# Python - Launch external program and quit script?

Tags: python, operating-system

I've wrote a little script to launch a program and send a mail if a program has quit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8

import psutil    
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import time
import os

program = "transmission-gtk"
if not program in [psutil.Process(i).name for i in psutil.get_pid_list()]:
   try:
      os.system(program)
      text = "but it has been restarted" 
   except IOError as e:
      text = "The restart failed!\n" + e

   time.sleep(2)

   msg = MIMEText("Transmission has been closed !!\n" + text)
   msg["From"] = "adr@wmail.fr"
   msg["To"] = "adr@wmail.fr"
   msg["Subject"] = "subject"
   p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t"], stdin=PIPE)
   p.communicate(msg.as_string())
```

The script is launched by cron, every 15 min.
All works, except one thing: **transmission quit at the same moment the script quits**...

I don't want to write a permanent script (raspberry-pi), so a `while` loop is not what I want.

Then, how to launch my program ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `os.system(program+'&')` to background the execution of your program.

Also, even if your program works, you should have a look at the `subprocess` module (which intends to replace `os.system()`, among other things).

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was just a problem of Display and environment variable for cron... Anyway, all solutions for this question can be found [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal)